# Работа со switch

Tags: java, switch, case

Придумал пример:

```
public class Pr1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("выберите цифру от 1 до 3 и узнаете свой траспорт");

    int a = scr.nextInt();
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("авто");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("мото");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("авиа");
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("вы выбрали " + a + " вариант - " + );
}}
```

Вопрос: Можно-ли сделать так (что добавить после +), чтобы при выборе, например, цифры 3 получилось: 
//авиа
//вы выбрали 3 вариант - авиа
или так:
//вы выбрали - авиа

Спасибо!

Comment: какие идеи есть?

Comment: Создай переменную и в case блоке задай ей значение. А потом используй её при выводе

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Pr1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("выберите цифру от 1 до 3 и узнаете свой траспорт");

    int a = scr.nextInt();
    String str="";
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            str = "авто";
            break;
        case 2:
            str = "мото";
            break;
        case 3:
            str = "авиа";
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(str + "\n" +"вы выбрали " + a + " вариант - " + str);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830522/Работа-со-switch
 */
package selectCase;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class Pr1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Выберите цифру от 1 до 3 и узнаете свой транспорт");
    String strV = new String("Вы выбрали");
    String strTransport = new String("");


    int a = scr.nextInt();
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            strTransport = "авто";
            break;
        case 2:
            strTransport = "мото";
            break;
        case 3:
             strTransport = "авиа";
            break;
    }
   System.out.println( strV + " " + strTransport );
}
}
```